# How to set 'Task.json' when i want to locate the lower folder before ‘make’？

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are many subfolers including 'Grab' in 'C++', and each folder has 'MakeFile'. I've set Task.json and Launch.json in 'C++', but each subfoler will compile its 'MakeFile' not just compile once in 'Grab'. How to set Task.json to realize when i Run the Grab.cpp in 'Grab'(but the folder opened in VSCode is the upper folder 'C++'), only 'MakeFile' in 'Grab' will be compiled.

Launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "make",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Task.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {

            "label": "make",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make", // i've tried "cd ./Grab; make",but...wrong
            "args": [
                ""
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```